# Element not found and else part is executed- Selenium web driver

Tags: java, jquery, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on Selenium WebDriver and using Java. If I perform the Logout function it is not finding the element through the ID. Below is the code:

[image]

```
Log.info("Clicking on Logout button");
//driver.findElement(By.id("moreLink")).click();
if(existsElement("logoutLink") == true) {
    WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("logoutLink"));
    actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).click().perform();
    Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else { 
    Log.info("element not present");
    System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");         
}
```

Below is the HTML tag:

```
<li>
    <a id="logoutLink" href="https://10.4.16.159/index/logout/">Log Out</a>
</li>
```

Comment: First, if your method existsElement() returns boolean, you don't need to match it with _true_. Second, is logout link displayed on the page, when you perform click on it, because it seems to be present on some kind of overlay. Lastly why are you doing mouse hover and not a direct click??

Comment: Give the code for **existsElement** method. We can improve it to work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.size()` method in if condition:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.id("logoutLink")).size() != 0){
```

or with `.isEmpty()` along with `!`:

```
if(!driver.findElements(By.id("logoutLink")).isEmpty()){
```

Comment: If i am using the above code getting some error.The method size() is undefined for the type By and else part i'm getting error.. Please help to fix this.. I'm new to selenium and java

Comment: @Amir see the updated one  with not `!`, `.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1)

```
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
menuHoverLink.click;
```

insted of:

```
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).click().perform();
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

OR

2) New method:

```
clickWhenTheElementIsClickable(By.id("logoutLink"), 10);

...
        protected void clickWhenTheElementIsClickable(By locator, long timeout) {
            WebDriverWait wait = (WebDriverWait)new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
            WebElement element = wait.until(
                    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
            element.click();
        }
```